# How can I paste a gif from the clipboard with xclip?

Tags: command-line, clipboard, xclip, screencasting

I'm trying to copy a gif into my clipboard such that I would be able to paste it into web applications (slack, github, etc.).

I have tried the following without any luck:

```
xclip -selection clipboard -t image/gif < /path/to/image.gif
```

Comment: How do you test there's no luck?

Comment: You roll a d20 before running the command. If the result is a 18 or more, you have luck.

Comment: I came across this problem recently while writing a script. The closest I have come to a solution is copying the path to the file, which really isn't much of a solution at all. At least it lets me conveniently paste the path into the file upload dialog... Also, I noticed that when I copy a GIF from Chrome using the rclick context menu, the image gets converted to a PNG. Doesn't look promising.

Comment: FWIW, that works perfectly fine for me with xclip 0.13.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
/opt/dragon --on-top --and-exit image.gif & sleep 0.1
/opt/dragon --on-top --and-exit cover.mp4 & sleep 0.3
```

and use `xdotool` to drag drop

Answer (score 0):

```
xclip -selection clipboard -t image/gif -i /path/to/image.gif
```